# android- how to add Header to GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am new to android. 
I want to add a header (sunday, monday, ....,sat)to grid as shown in following figure. is ther any work around to design a header for grid.
[image]

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android) for a discussion on how to work around this limitation

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no support for header or footer views in `GridView`s, add a simple layout with the desired fields above your `GridView`. Note that this way the header will **NOT** be scrollable along with the `GridView`.