# Android GridView add header and footer like listview

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

Maybe you want to call `addHeaderView()` or `addFooterView()` in `GridView`, which it does not have.

It's nature that we want to add header view or a footer view to a `GridView`. Maybe your have been searching a long time like me, but finally find no solution.

Here, I will give out an solution.

Comment: You need to add separate layout after and before GridView in your xml file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I post this answer just want people who come here can get what the want.

#### Let's have a look the screen snapshot.

[image: Screen Shot]

#### the usage is very simple

```
GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) v.findViewById(R.id.ly_image_list_grid);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_header_view, null);
View footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_footer_view, null);
gridView.addHeaderView(headerView);
gridView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

It'a single file project, now it hosts at [GitHub: https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter)

You can follow the link above to access the code. Happy coding.

Comment: @inVINCEable, thank you. It's ok now: https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter

Comment: @srain Hi, I have implemented with this library. But I am facing one problem and its my requirement too. That is the header and footer should fit to the screen width not the grid items.The grid items should have right and left margins. How can I achieve using this library ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe set margin / padding to grid items.

Comment: @srain how to add sections in this library  we can only use one section here with its header and foooter ? but how can i  add 2 sections with its header , content of section , footer

Comment: @Erum you can add multiple header or footer.

Comment: @srain  no i am asking can i made sections in this lib and for each section i need header and footer is this possible ? and also how can we integrate loadMoreData on footer click ?

Comment: @srain  if u know the way pls share how can we do ?

Comment: @Erum I think they are not sections, it is TabIndicators or a specify view.

Comment: @srain  pls check tabindicators fragment i m talking about that fragment which is opening under tabindicator

Comment: @Erum sorry, I'm a little confused. My hangouts: liaohuqiu@gmail.com

Comment: You can use RecyclerView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: hi, how can i update the headerview from the adapter? i mean lets say i have a textview inside the header, from the adapter after i changed the list, i want to count total and save into the textview inside the header. how can i do that? please advice

Comment: @AlfredAngkasa hi, for now, the best solution is use recyclerview instead of  this view.

Comment: @srain, hi. thanks for your answer. I done it with view. I mean i send the view to the adapter, and do some logic at the adapter. it works. :)

Answer (score 6):

To add a Header to the GridView, use the `HeaderGridView` by Google.

Just copy this [class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java) into your project and use it instead of the default `GridView`, and you will be able to add header using the following line:

```
 gridView.addHeaderView(customView);
```

Source: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617051/1364896)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create layout with two columns and use ListView. In getView you should manipulate with columns and set there some data.

Also you can create just one column in first and last row. It will look like header or footer.

Besides, you can look through these links:

https://github.com/munix/GridViewHeader

https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders