# Android ListView multiple Headers

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I would like to create a ListView like this, for example:

```
JOHN           ANDREW          LUKE
01               15             55
10               25             60
12               30
```

that is, each column with its data, in practice each name must be the header of each column .... how can I set the Adapter?
Do you have any idea?

I looked around but I could not find examples.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a `GridView` for this. See this:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

You need to add a `HeaderGridView` and it should work:

[Add a Header to a GridView (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android)