# Android textview inside gridview

Tags: android

I put a textview inside the header of a gridview but if I need to scroll the textview it not scroll, instead scroll the gridview.

This is the code:

```
<GridWithHeader
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridWithHeader"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

And this is the content of header

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/row_2"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_header_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

where is the error or how can I solve the problem?

Comment: GridWithHeader - what is is?

Comment: check this out [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android)

Comment: my problem is that I need to scroll the textview inside the gridview...I already have the header on gridview

Answer (score 0):

try to delete from "GridWithHeader" `android:focusableInTouchMode` and `android:focusable="true"` and add them to you Textview like this:

```
          <TextView              
          android:id="@+id/text_header_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
          android:fadeScrollbars="false"
          android:scrollbars="vertical" >
```

Comment: nothing, the textview can't scroll because gridview scroll before the textview!