# Create a custom grid view with first item in one column and other in 2 columns

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, navigation-drawer

i need a gridview very much like this ......[image]

and i want to use this Gridview in a navigation drawer in place of Listview..

if anyone has any idea about that....please help

Comment: do you have a permanant(static) number of data to fill in the grid?

Comment: yes,i have static data

Comment: you can follow the answer you got right down here to create the grid once you get finished in making that post your code I can help you with placing it in navigation drawer

Comment: i have already place grid in navigation drawer just need that header

Comment: okk fine happy coding...

Comment: hey have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry man. HeaderView and FooterView is there to save you.

Have a look at this [GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter)

Comment: its working...i just need some modifications...after that its working according to my need now......thanks

Answer (score 0):

take a look [here](https://github.com/google/iosched) google/iosched. Especially for SessionsFragment and CollectionView in ui package