# How to set full row section view for gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

I have tried and worked for listview with section view between list items and it works fine for me .
When I tried for gridview it is showing till the each item width not full row because obviously gridview comes with 2 or more items in a row .

So I want to make full row as section item between grid view items .
I searched elsewhere before posting here so can anyone help me ??

Comment: Good question,I also need the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with `GridView` widget because it works in terms of columns. You can hack it with adding 3 `Views` in a row if that will work for you, but it will have obvious drawbacks such as you won't be able to put a text there that will take more that 1/3 of the screen width.

Use `RecyclerView` vs `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` instead: http://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/

Comment: Can we add header n footer view to this listview??

Comment: You can. Refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android

Comment: I know this answer implemented same but do recyclerview has a header and footer view??

Comment: No, this is not a built-in functionality for `RecyclerView`. You can do that manually by adding a new view type.