# How to add header in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I want know how to add header like Play Store with gridview in horizontal mode
[image]

Comment: the are plugins  to help you do that -- http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/ -- or by code -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android

Comment: If the below answer solves your problem, you should accept it, so that it makes it easy for the coming users to find solution to the problem.

Comment: This would seem to be the way to go today ... https://tonicartos.github.io/SuperSLiM/

Comment: or possibly the older https://github.com/DWorkS/AStickyHeader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horiontal gridview can be achieved by [Recycler view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

For adding the heading, put a textview and the recycler view in a linear layout (with vertical orientation of course), something like this :

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical" ..... >
    <Textview ...... />
    <RecyclerView .... />
</LinearLayout>
```

And for achiving the horizontal view in recycler view, set the layoutmanager in java as :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Note that, **`wrap_content`** is not yet supported by `RecyclerView`. To overcome that, you'd have to either

1) set `minHeight/minWidth` attribute.

2) use a custom layout manager

Comment: Hey for example, if the <TexView> before an RecyclerView is bigger, i can use the ScrollView without error "scrollview can host only one direct child"

Comment: @HelioSoaresJunior : I didn't get your question. Can you rephrase it more clearly?

Comment: For example, if I have more views below of RecyclerView, it will create the scroll automatically? (Views off the list)

Comment: No, it won't. If your content needs scrolling, you should place everything above inside a scrollview tag.

Comment: thanks, i will try, when I used the listview I can not use another scroll