# how to add columns headers android

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I am new to development of android apps but have experince in .net programming what I am looking for here is how to add headers to the columns in gridview  ,any one have a clue of how can I add columns headers in the gridview.
thanks in advance

here is my code after modification

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Column1 "
            android:textColor="#2582C5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Column1"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#000222"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Column2"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#000222"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Column3"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#000222"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Column4"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#000222"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#000222" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24617051/7795876   this might help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a Header to a GridView (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android)

Comment: You need to create horizontal linear layout with column headers. Add it above gridview.

Comment: I have added it as you suggested but the columns are not show up